# Cannot rename nodeset in ECK

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-cloud

I am trying to rename a nodeset in my ECK cluster. Below is my Elastisearch cluster yaml:

```
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1 
kind: Elasticsearch 
metadata: 
  name: elastic-test
spec: 
  version: 7.11.1
  auth:
    roles:
    - secretName: elastic-roles-secret
    fileRealm:
    - secretName: elastic-filerealm-secret
  nodeSets: 
  - name: default
    count: 1 
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false 
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: azure-pvc
      spec:
        storageClassName: ""
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 25Gi
        volumeName: elasticsearch-azure-pv
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        initContainers:
        - name: install-plugins
          command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - |
            bin/elasticsearch-plugin install --batch ingest-attachment
```

I want to change the nodeset name from **default** to **default2**.
However, the new pod created is stuck on Pending.

kubectl describe the new pod:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m12s  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m12s  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 3 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

Because both the old PVC was not deleted, the new PVC cannot bind to the same PV. AFAIK, for the intended behaviour the old PVC and pod should be deleted and the new pod and PVC can bind to the PV.

To provide some context, my deployment environment only allows me to apply yaml files (no running kubectl delete), and the goal is to add the ingest-attachment plugin. So I am trying to restart the existing pod by renaming it.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using?

Comment: client version: v1.20.4, server version: v1.18.10

Comment: Are you using any particular cloud provider? Have you created the PV and PVC by hand? Could you post the output of kubectl get PVC -A and kubectl get pv?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I am using AKS, and the PV is created by hand to use Azure files as storage. The PV and PVC is working fine, I just want to restart the pod without using `kubectl delete`